# How to store declared files from manifest file into HTML5 AppCache except storing page with manifest-attribute?

Tags: asp.net, html, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I'm creating a web-application in ASP.net, which i want to access offline. I need to store some static html-sites into the appcache. The only option i see is to load the appcache manifest file by extending the html-tag in Site.Master with the manifest attribute. But now every page i'm calling is getting stored into the appcache.

e.g. every .aspx-page like Default.aspx inherit the masterpage including the html-tag:

**Site.Master**

```
<html manifest="Manifest.appcache">
```

**Manifest.appcache**

```
CACHE:
Default_off.html

FALLBACK:
/Default /Default_off.html
```

finally the browser store my Default_off.html AND Default of Default.aspx. So even if i declare the FALLBACK, the page call the Default(.aspx) page.

Somebody knows how to avoid the page with the manifest attribute is getting stored in appcache or an alternative way so just the files declared in the manifest file are getting stored?!

Comment: i actually thought about adding the manifest tag to Default_off.html and calling the page in the first place and redirect immediately to the Default.aspx. Or call it in a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:** There's no flawless solution for this problem, cause the page which includes the manifest-attribute is always saved in the appcache. So i put the manifest-attribute into an empty website, which i include as an object (iframe should work too):

```
<object type="text/html" data="Manifest.htm" Width="1" Height="1" style="border:none">
```

Now the empty Manifest.htm is saved, but there is no Default.aspx site which block the Default target or get called on another way.